# Are there repositories or organized collections of mathematica notebooks?

Tags: notebooks

I was wondering if there was one place where researchers upload their mathematica notebooks used for specialized research once if they choose to make it public

Comment: http://packagedata.net/ and on github/gitlab

Comment: https://www.notebookarchive.org/search

Answer (score 4):

There used to be   https://library.wolfram.com/

[image]

But this does not seem to be active any more. Instead you can go to this link which has more recent archives, including the notebook archive given in comments above.

https://resources.wolframcloud.com/

[image]